# Finding Square Roots

Tags: number-theory

Well, i have  a method to find square roots to any number.
for Eg To find $\sqrt{58}$ or any number. We have to find which perfect square is place before it. 49 is placed before 58.
What we have to do is enter the value in this expression.$\sqrt{a}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}$ here a is 49. and we get $\space 7+\frac{1}{14}=7.071$
Then we have to find how much the number is place after perfect square(49). $58-49=9$ Multiply 9 with $0.071$ we get $0.63$ so $\sqrt{58} \approx 7.63$
How is my new way?

Answer (score 0):

That's just the approximation of binomial expansion. It doesn't work for all but is a very good approximation for many. You used $\sqrt{58} = \sqrt{49+9} = 7\sqrt{1+9/49}$ = $7(1+$$9\over2*49$$)$ $= 7+$$9\over14$ = 7.63
Binomial approximation states - $$(1+x)^n = (1+nx)$$  when  $x <<<1$

Comment: It will work good for all,

Comment: My another question is. Is there any formula for this? $$ \sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}...........\sqrt{n}$$

Comment: find sqrt of 8 with that

Comment: The above method is the formula. You will get sqrt(8) as 3. It's 2.828 actually

Comment: Refer this :  ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram09.pdf  That's a paper on what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

You ask: how is this method of computing square roots?

The answer is: it's pretty good. As written, it's how the Babylonians computed square roots. This is sometimes called "The Babylonian Method."

You can do better if you iterate it. Say you are trying to calculate the square root of $S$. If you call $x_0$ the nearest square root  below the square root you're looking for, i.e. $x_0 = \lfloor \sqrt S \rfloor$, then you can view your approximation as the average of $x_0$ and $S/x_0$. Call your approximate $x_1$. So
$$x_1 = \frac{1}{2} \left( x_0 + \frac{S}{x_0}\right).$$
For instance,
$$ 7.64 \approx \frac{1}{2} \left( 7 + \frac{58}{7}\right).$$

You can then iterate this procedure, and come up with
$$ x_2 = \frac{1}{2} \left( x_1 + \frac{S}{x_1}\right),$$
and so on. Each one will be closer than the last. In fact, the convergence is quadratic, and this is a very simple example of a non-optimized Newton's method.